# Pass list of ids to search query

Tags: feature-request, support, search

I've made a dataSE query that gives to me a lot of questions ids.

Now I want to pass these ids to search query to find questions on the site as there I can see an actual state and the interface is better. How can I do that?

https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/830539#resultSets

803894
800956
800759
798616
794570
791995
790965
788281
786965
785455
784896
784620
783444
782746
781314
780300
778811
778101
775914
775749
774968
774526
774404
774212
773456
773149
773132
771610
768254
767776
766966
765267
764960
763795
763148
761372
759447
759300
759102
757562
757281
756005
754166
744722
744404
743960
743714
739366
737911
734374
731728
729758
729386
728973
728464
728060
727410
726480
722862
720058
718666
718527
717564
717420
716986
716056
714978
713564
712294
709578
706592
706561
706344
706006
703298
702057
701514
700778
700565
700051
700022
695153
694159
694022
693032
692857
692541
691872
690884
690503
687954
687573
685078
684637
681367
679523
678528
677399
675997
675396
674174
672514
671267
670927
666907
664547
664396
663574
663068
662975
661372
660125
660037
658905
656559
656480
656221
654607
653766
652985
652701
652642
649796
647287
646499
645770
645621
645318
645175
640233
639406
638153
635065
634932
631768
628648
626107
624237
624092
622842
622436
618827
616658
615784
615610
614834
614029
613365
613324
612946
612910
608578
606187
605672
603832
603128
601035
599168
598264
597334
596761
596203
595480
594929
594393
594130
593443
592733
591301
590085
589391
587806
586485
586450
585568
584158
577898
576763
576555
576198
575996
575745
571907
571051
569637
568886
568873
565923
563920
563657
563174
562838
562748
560035
558710
557680
557508
554772
553557
549080
547389
547240
544708
544397
543276
541920
541747
540679
540028
538272
536660
536601
533711
530331
521122
520148
519342
518639
518361
517676
516631
516619
514994
514942
512598
510882
510411
509857
509618
509107
508785
508453
507857
507494
507243
505558
503630
500364
498585
497920
497378
497177
496209
495324
493723
490554
489446
489096
487958
487762
487501
487491
487432
487284
486176
484860
481200
480319
479232
478939
478809
478624
478155
478087
476962
476062
475462
475277
474644
473659
473067
473006
472805
472691
472076
470142
468046
467529
467443
462676
462582
460431
459308
457662
455374
455033
454601
454574
454497
454139
453035
452497
452487
450704
450559
450407
448198
445721
445599
444788
444443
438449
435790
435653
434602
434502
429916
427729
427574
426518
423831
422221
420119
418447
417943
417303
416229
414938
410168
408037
402636
402164
401558
390764
372090
371964
362975
361507
361059
358008
352859
349832
332914
285433

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What does "pass to a search query" mean? Are you after a link to the post? Do you want to know whether they're closed or not? If you want the link name the column `[Post Link]`, i.e. `id as [Post Link]`

Comment: You can use queries like `user:309650`. I like something like that, but for  post ids not user ids. And I want it to support multiple ids.

Comment: Ah, you want all of these questions in a single list due to the bug you've found in your other question?

Comment: Not due to the bug. Simply a search interface shows title and preview. And I can exclude some questions by tag from there if they are already edited (actually it's a list of questions to be checked after wrong synonimization of the tags).

Comment: Why downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/830890/questions-with-details) shows the title (with a link to the question itself), the tags and (the first part of) the question body. As far as I know, there's no built-in way to get this information rendered like e.g. search results. You might be able to build something like that using the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I want site search results to accept copied ids in its query, not dataSE to show list as search results.

Comment: I understand, but that's not possible. The next best thing I can offer you is this SEDE query.